# Non sequential ftp script

Tags: ftp, aix, nonsequential

**Scenario:**
I have to transfer approx 3000 files, 30 to 35 MB each from one server to another (Both servers are IBM-AIX servers).
These files are in .gz format. They are unzipped at the destination using gunzip command to b of use.

**The way i am doing it now:**
I have made .sh files containing ftp scripts of 500 files each. These .sh files when run, transfer the file to the destination. At the destination i keep on checking how many files have arrived, as soon as 100 files have arrived, i run gunzip for these 100 files, then again the same for the next 100 files and so on. I run gunzip for a batch of 100 just to save on time.

**What is in my mind:**
I am in search of a command or any other way which will ftp my files to the destination, and as soon as 100 files are transferred they are started for unzipping **BUT** this unzipping should not pause the transfer for the remaining files.

**Script that i tried:**

```
ftp -n 192.168.0.22 << EOF
quote user username
quote pass password
cd /gzip_files/files
lcd /unzip_files/files
prompt n
bin
mget file_00028910*gz
! gunzip file_00028910*gz
mget file_00028911*gz
! gunzip file_00028911*gz
mget file_00028912*gz
! gunzip file_00028912*gz
mget file_00028913*gz
! gunzip file_00028913*gz
mget file_00028914*gz
! gunzip file_00028914*gz
bye
```

The drawback in the above code is that when the

```
! gunzip file_00028910*gz
```

lines is executing, the ftp for the next batch i.e ftp for ( file_00028911*gz ) is paused, hence wasting lot of time and loss of bandwidth utilization.
The ! mark is used to run Operating system commands within ftp prompt.

Hope i have explained my scenario properly. Will update the post if i get a solution, if any one already has a solution do reply.

Regards
Yash.

Comment: Can you use rsync? Also, scp can copy with dynamic compression (that's option "-C").

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to do it on a UNIX system you probably have Perl installed. You might try the following Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my @files = @ARGV; # get files from command line

my $server = '192.168.0.22';
my $user   = 'username';
my $pass   = 'password';

my $gunzip_after = 100; # collect up to 100 files

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($server) or die "failed connect to the server: $!";
$ftp->login($user,$pass) or die "login failed";

my $pid_gunzip;
while (1) {
    my @collect4gunzip;

    GET_FILES:
    while (my $file = shift @files) {
        my $local_file = $ftp->get($file);
        if ( ! $local_file ) {
            warn "failed to get $file: ".$ftp->message;
            next;
        }
        push @collect4gunzip,$local_file;
        last if @collect4gunzip == $gunzip_after;
    }

    @collect4gunzip or last; # no more files ?

    while ( $pid_gunzip && kill(0,$pid_gunzip)) {
        # gunzip is still running, wait because we don't want to run multiple
        # gunzip instances at the same time
        warn "wait for last gunzip to return...\n";
        wait();

        # instead of waiting for gunzip to return we could go back to retrieve
        # more files and add them to @collect4gunzip
        # goto GET_FILES;
    }

    # last gunzip is done, start to gunzip collected files
    defined( $pid_gunzip = fork()) or die "fork failed: $!";
    if ( ! $pid_gunzip ) {
        # child process should run gunzip
        # maybe one needs so split it into multipl gunzip calls to make
        # sure, that the command line does not get too long!!
        system( ['gunzip', @collect4gunzip ]);
        # child will exit once done
        exit(0);
    }

    # parent continues with getting more files
}
```

It's not tested, but at least it passes the syntax check.

Answer (score 0):

One of two solutions.  Don't call gunzip directly.  Call "blah" and "blah" is a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
gunzip "$@" &
```

so the gunzip is put into the background, the script returns immediately, and you continue with the FTP.  The other thought is to just add the & to the sh command -- I bet that would work just as well.  i.e. within the ftp script, do:

```
! gunzip file_00028914*gz &
```

But... I believe you are somewhat leading yourself astray.  rsync and other solutions are the way to go for many reasons.